# Getting undefined values while using UseContext in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Context that I created to use `useState` across my component:

`context.js`:

```
const searchContext = React.createContext();
```

This is where I created a `useState` with `searchText` with initial state as an empty string.

`Header.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { searchContext } from "./context";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Motherboard from "./Components/Motherboard";

function Header() {
  const[searchText,setSearchText] = useState("");

  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#191C27", paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0 }}
    >
      <Navbar
        variant="light"
        expand="lg"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#191C27" }}
      >
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll">
            <img src={options} alt="options" width="30px" />
          </Navbar.Toggle>
          <Navbar.Brand className="mr-auto" href="#">
          <Link to='home'>
          <img
              className="logoIcon"
              src={logo}
              alt="logo"
              style={{ width: 130 }}
            />
            </Link>           
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
            <Nav
              className="ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0"
              style={{ maxHeight: "100px", marginRight: "5%" }}
              navbarScroll
            >
              <Nav.Link>
                <Link to='/motherboard' className="links">
                Motherboard
                </Link>
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                <Link to='/processor' className="links">
                Processor
                </Link>
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link>
              <Link to='/ram' className="links">
                RAM
                </Link>
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link>
              <Link to='/hdd' className="links">
                HDD
                </Link>
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link>
              <Link to='/graphic' className="links">
                Cabinet
                </Link>
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
          <Form className="d-flex" style={{ marginRight: "2%" }}> 
          <searchContext.Provider value={searchText}>
          <Motherboard></Motherboard>
          </searchContext.Provider>
            <FormControl
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              onChange={event => {setSearchText(event.target.value)}}
              className="mr-2"
              aria-label="Search"
              style={{background:'transparent', borderRadius:0, color:'white'}}
            />
          </Form>
```

Now I tried using my `useContext` and called the `useState` value `searchText` here in `Motherboard` component. But getting some `undefined` errors while running.

`Motherboard.js`:

```
import {searchContext} from '../context'

const dummy = Array.from(Array(10));

function Motherboard(props) {
  let context = useContext(searchContext);

  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  // const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);

  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("/product?limit=50&page=1&category=motherboard")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, "res");
        dispatch({
          type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS,
          payload: res.data.products,
        });
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const styleCol = {
    backgroundColor: "#0F0F13",
  };

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div className='loadDiv'>
        <ClipLoader size="150" color="white" style={{marginTop: -200}}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="filterDiv">
      <Banner />
      <Container fluid="md">
        <Row>
          <Col lg={3} style={styleCol} className="colFilter">
            <div>
              <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#191C27" }}>
                <Accordion>
                  <AccordionSummary
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                  >
                    <Typography>SORT BY PRICE</Typography>
                  </AccordionSummary>
                  <div className="filterDiv">
                    <AccordionDetails>
                      <FormControl component="fieldset">
                        <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="gender1">
                          <FormControlLabel
                            value="hightolow"
                            control={<Radio />}
                            label="Highest to Lowest"
                            className="radioBtn"
                          />
                          <FormControlLabel
                            value="lowtohigh"
                            control={<Radio />}
                            label="Lowest to Highest"
                            className="radioBtn"
                          />
                        </RadioGroup>
                      </FormControl>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                  </div>
                </Accordion>
              </div>
              <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#191C27" }}>
                <Accordion>
                  <AccordionSummary
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                  >
                    <Typography className="heading">SUB CATEGORY</Typography>
                  </AccordionSummary>
                  <div className="filterDiv">
                    <AccordionDetails>
                      <FormControl component="fieldset">
                        <RadioGroup aria-label="processor" name="prcocessor">
                          <FormControlLabel
                            value="hightolow"
                            control={<Radio />}
                            label="INTEL"
                            className="radioBtn"
                          />
                          <FormControlLabel
                            value="lowtohigh"
                            control={<Radio />}
                            label="AMD"
                            className="radioBtn"
                          />
                        </RadioGroup>
                      </FormControl>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                  </div>
                </Accordion>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col
            xs={12}
            lg={9}
            sm={12}
            md={12}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#0F0F13", paddingTop: 27 }}
          >
            <Row>
              {products.filter((product) => {
                  if(context.searchText == '') {
                    return product
                  }
                  else if(product.productName.toLowerCase.includes(context.searchText.toLowerCase())){
                    return product
                  }}).map((product, index) => {
               return (
                  <Col key={index} lg={4} md={6} xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <div
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to define value as object. the error is probably due to the value not being an object

```
<searchContext.Provider value={{ searchText }}>
  <Motherboard></Motherboard>
</searchContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting 'includes is not a function' errors. Does this has anything to do with the change ?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote `context.searchText`, you have to store an object inside the value of the provider:

```
<searchContext.Provider value={{ searchText }}>
  <Motherboard />
</searchContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

use context instead of context.searchText in MotherBoard.js because you are passing a string as the value in the provider so when call the context using useContext , it gives the latest value of the provider which is what you typed in the search box.